# Devstack - Changing IP address after installation

Tags: openstack, devstack

I have devstack installed on a ubuntu 12.04 and I could get logged into Dashboard , Now I changed the IP of my ubuntu machine. After changing the IP, I couldn't log into Dashboard anymore

I gets the following error message. I can see my old IP in the error message.

```
ConnectionError at /auth/login/
HTTPConnectionPool(host='OLD_IP_ADDRESS', port=35357): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.0/tokens (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 113] No route to host)

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://NEW_IP_ADDRESS/auth/login/
Django Version:     1.4.5
Exception Type:     ConnectionError
Exception Value:    
HTTPConnectionPool(host='OLD_IP_ADDRESS', port=35357): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.0/tokens (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 113] No route to host)
Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send, line 246
  Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python
  Python Version:   2.7.3
  Python Path:  
   ['/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../..',
   '/opt/stack/python-keystoneclient',
   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
   '/opt/stack/python-glanceclient/setuptools_git-1.0b1-py2.7.egg',
   '/opt/stack/python-glanceclient',
   '/opt/stack/python-cinderclient',
```

Is there a documented procedure available to change the IP address manually ? 
My New IP doesn't have connection to internet so I wouldn't be able to redeploy devstack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys for your answers..

I missed to update my answer, I fixed that issue in an easy way.

Solution is first run unstack.sh and then run stack.sh once more. It will do the necessary fix. Since I haven't made much progress with Devstack after installation it makes me more confident to run stack.sh

For the second time when you run stack.sh its not needed to connect to internet, So my issue is fixed.

Feel free to share your thoughts on this.

Comment: This worked for me, but easier and faster than rummaging around a bunch of configuration files.  But not sure if it will purge everything.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the IP address hard-coded in OpenStack configuration files generated by devstack.  They are stored in /etc/ and elsewhere.

http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/how-to-change-ip-address-after-openstack-installation-via-devstack.html

Answer (score -1):

Here's a few steps I've taken to get back online.

- backup the answers file...

  `cp packstack-answers-20130417.txt packstack-answers.txt-SAVE`
- replace ip addresses...

  `sed -i '/s/10\.10\.248\.11/10\.32\.70\.10/g' packstack-answers-20130417.txt`
- Delete the cinder loopback devices, installer fails if it exists

  `losetup -d /dev/loop0`
- List what's left mounted via the loop.

  `losetup -a`

  `rm /var/lib/cinder/cinder-volumes`
- Now rerun the deploy scripts

  `packstack --answer-file=packstack-answers-20130417.txt`

Fix up other IP addressing concerns with nova-manage in the CLI.

Should work from here.